Bad clash between biblatex, polyglossia and fontspec
I have an MWE where things seem to have been set appropriately, but upon processing I get the error:
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font ArabicTypesetting(0) does not contain the "Cyrillic" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily command.

which is a bit unitelligible because \cyrillicfont is defined and the font does have the Cyrillic script. Why is it using ArabicTypesetting is hard to understand.
The problem seems to reside with the URL entry in the Bib file -- which is even weider -- because that is also a perfectly good URL, but removing it clears the error.
Processing is with:
rm *.bbl
xelatex file
biber file
xelatex file

Download Arabic Typesseting font
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
}

@book{polya-ar,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {\textarabic{ﻚﻴﻓ ﺖﺤﻟ ﻢﺳﺎٔﻟﺓ ﺮﻳﺎﻀﻳﺓ : ﻢﻨﺣﻯ ﺝﺪﻳﺩ ﻒﻳ ﺎﻠﻃﺮﻴﻗﺓ ﺎﻟﺮﻳﺎﻀﻳﺓ }},
        publisher = {\textarabic{ﺎﻠﻤﻨﻈﻣﺓ ﺎﻠﻋﺮﺒﻳﺓ ﻞﻠﺗﺮﺠﻣﺓ،}},
        address = {\textarabic{ ﺐﻳﺭﻮﺗ، ﻞﺒﻧﺎﻧ}},
        date = {2016},
        langid = {ar},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        url = {http://www.vixri.ru/d/P%20O%20J%20A%20D.%20%20_KAK%20REShAT'%20ZADAChU.pdf},
        langid = {russian},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
%\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}

% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Has to be set late because of bidi:
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Arabic Typesetting}
% redefine \textarabic{} to never be italic
\let\oldtextarabic\textarabic
\renewcommand{\textarabic}{\upshape\oldtextarabic}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


You seem to have an outdated version of Polyglossia, because the message I get is
! Package polyglossia Error: The current main monospace font,
(polyglossia)                lmmono10-regular, does not contain the
(polyglossia)                "Cyrillic" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfonttt with
(polyglossia)                \newfontfamily command

So you need \newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{...}[...].
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
}

@book{polya-ar,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {\textarabic{ﻚﻴﻓ ﺖﺤﻟ ﻢﺳﺎٔﻟﺓ ﺮﻳﺎﻀﻳﺓ : ﻢﻨﺣﻯ ﺝﺪﻳﺩ ﻒﻳ ﺎﻠﻃﺮﻴﻗﺓ ﺎﻟﺮﻳﺎﻀﻳﺓ }},
        publisher = {\textarabic{ﺎﻠﻤﻨﻈﻣﺓ ﺎﻠﻋﺮﺒﻳﺓ ﻞﻠﺗﺮﺠﻣﺓ،}},
        address = {\textarabic{ ﺐﻳﺭﻮﺗ، ﻞﺒﻧﺎﻧ}},
        date = {2016},
        langid = {ar},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        url = {http://www.vixri.ru/d/P%20O%20J%20A%20D.%20%20_KAK%20REShAT'%20ZADAChU.pdf},
        langid = {russian},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=three,
            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Inconsolatazi4}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newfontface{\arabicfont}{Arabic Typesetting Regular}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=./,
  Script=Arabic,
  Scale=1.2,
]

%\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}

% Bibliographical citations:

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Has to be set late because of bidi:
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
% redefine \textarabic{} to never be italic
\NewCommandCopy{\oldtextarabic}{\textarabic}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textarabic}{O{}m}{\oldtextarabic[#1]{\upshape#2}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

Please note that \let\oldtextarabic\textarabic is not a good strategy and your redefinition of \textarabic is wrong, because it applies \upshape at the outer level.
The font definition is more complex because I didn't want to install the font in the system. However, the Arabic font you suggest to use is very incomplete:
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻯ (U+FEEF) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺝ (U+FE9D) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺩ (U+FEA9) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺭ (U+FEAD) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﻳ (U+FEF3) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ﺓ (U+FE93) in font [./Arabic Typesetting Regular
.ttf]/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;!

If I use a different Arabic font with
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{XB Niloofar}

the warnings are no longer present. But, of course, the typesetting is wrong.


Indeed! Upgrading TL solved it.

Is it true that Stix 2 has Cyrillic, but not a mono-spaced Cyrillic?

@TeXApprentice look at the message: lmmono10-regular it is using latin modern monospace
